# Angular installation

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I want to install Angular version 4.* on my windows 7.
I am currently using Angular version 1.6.*

I tried following command

```
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@next --save
```

But its not working

Can any one please guide me to install and to create angular 4 project..

Comment: Could you please consider visiting [angular.io quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) page?

Comment: You can watch it, it have full steps for installation angular 4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52gVTMk9__E

Comment: refer this link its helpful https://coursetro.com/posts/code/55/How-to-Install-an-Angular-4-App

Comment: Ok, i think i answered to other question here.

So, the solution is "Create one angular project by *** ng new PROJECT_NAME *** and then update your "@angular/compiler-cli" to 4.2.0 under "devDependencies" of package.json file.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Make sure you have node version above 6.9 and npm above 3
2. Check the version by using node --version and npm --version
3. Install angular cli using npm install -g @angular/cli
4. -g installs the angular globally on your system and you just have to run this command only once
5. Create the angular project using ‘ng new angularprojectname’
6. Go to that project folder and check the angular version by ‘ng -v’
7. Upgrade this version to angular 4 by running this command-

   For Windows-
           npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next @angular/platform-server@next @angular/router@next @angular/animations@next --save

For Linux/Mac-
npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@next --save

Make sure to upgrade the typescript version by running command-
npm install typescript@2.2.1 --save

Ignore whatever warning it shows up and now check the angular version by ‘ng -v’
The version has changed from 2.2.4 to 4.1.0

You can also check all the info about your angular cli in package.json file.

Comment: Did upto step 6. Got angular 4 itself. Thanks

Comment: up to step 6 it is installing latest angular version. can you please tell me how to switch to angular specific version

Comment: Install typescript using npm install –g typescript

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install npm -g install angular-cli

And write sudo if you are using mac or ubantu

Then go to directory where you want project and then ng new PROJECTNAME

It will create project

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this to update the answer.

If you want to install the latest angular version others answers are for you.

If you want to install a specific version of angular ([Get your version number here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli))
 You should use the below command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@VERSION_NUMBER
```

for example, if you want to install angular **1.4.9** command should be like below

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also found the same issue while installing.

> Please Do **check npm and nodejs version and upgrade them**.

I'd like to recommend **node v6.x.x** and **npm 4.x.x** or higher

Comment: I also face this issue in ubuntu but it was fixed after udating npm and nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for latest angular version use this command to install

```
npm -g install @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to structure AngularJS applications. When you begin to upgrade these applications to Angular, some will turn out to be much more easy to work with than others. There are a few key techniques and patterns that you can apply to future proof apps even before you begin the migration.

- Follow the AngularJS Style Guide
- Using a Module Loader
- Migrating to TypeScript
- Using Component Directives
- [Upgrade with ngUpgrade](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade)

Or up can follow the official document of [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

For installing Angular 4 follow below simple steps:

1. Install node.js and npm(they are required dependencies. npm is automatically installed on installing node.js). You can install it
   from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)
2. With the help of npm install angular CLI. Type the following command in your command prompt: npm install -g @angular/cli
3. If you are still facing some problems you have to install git. You can install it from [here](https://git-scm.com/)
4. Now to create an angular 4 project using Angular CLI type the following command:
   ng new [Project_Name]
   This will create an Angualr 4 project.
   5.To start the server and get your project up and running type following in command line:
   ng serve

Remember you should be inside the project folder before starting the server. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have some libraries, Like

```
angular-material, angular-cdk`
```

etc...
Add all those and Try.
It will work for sure.
And you will be able to run the project

Comment: Why he needs material and cdk if he doesn't want to, also his issue with the angular itself now.

Comment: These two libraries are not part of the core Angular4 deployment, and won't help him. Nor does it answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

Install angular cli globally.

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Get git pull from repository:-

**[https://github.com/blazehub/ng-cli-starter.git]**

to get ready made production ready project structure.