# Is installing node and npm must when we need to create new angular project on visual studio code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am new to angular, all the tutorials I came across to create angular project used angular cli (also installed node and npm before this). My employer is asking me to work on visual studio-code(IDE). Is it necessary for me to install node and npm before starting any angular project in vs-code (IDE). I searched enough but couldn't find any material regarding this even in vs-code website. Can anyone please provide any link or please tell me about how to start a new angular project using vs-code. I use ubuntu 16.04 os.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is : `Yes` if you want to use `angular-cli` which is the recommended way.

You will also need `node/npm` if you plan on using `typescript`. Because you will have to compile `ts` to `js`

However, you can always use angular with javascript and in that case, you will not need node/npm

But going with `angular-cli` is the best way.

Comment: ok I need to use typescript so I will have to install node and npm, but can I bypass angular-cli and start using vs-code instead?

Comment: why do you want to skip angular-cli ? if you skip angular-cli, how will you compile ts to js ?

Comment: and just to clarify, angular-cli is the cli, and vs-code is IDE. They are not related in any way. You need to use both

Comment: Sorry, I assumed angular-cli to be command line interface environment to develop an angular application, and vs-code to be gui based to do achieve the same.

Comment: no, vs-code is just ide. you need both cli nd vs-code. accept the answer if it helped

Comment: IF possible can you please tell me how node, npm, angular-cli are related to developing angular application on vs-code, I mean what is the purpose of each one in the development of angular application? Thanks

Comment: node is needed for npm, And npm is the package manager used to install angular-cli. You will use angular-cli to scaffold the project and run commands like ng serve. VS-code is your editor in which you will do the development

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is just the code editor. You can open the created angular project from VS Code. First install npm from [this](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) link. Then, use the description in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44041183/7338196) or [this](https://cli.angular.io/) link to install angular-cli. Finally, if you want to open the generated project from VS code, open terminal window, cd in to the project folder, then type `code .` and hit enter.